# Can anyone identify this insect larvae please?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

[image: translucent body]

I found thus tiny creature in my shower its about 19mm in length with a see through body and moves much like a caterpillar.

Comment: It would be great if you could add some information where this image was taken.

Comment: It looks like a Diptera larva, and it is most certainly not a parasite. I've seen many similar larvae in the Limoniidae subfamily.